# I would like to place Icons or Images or User Controls inside the activity in Android 2.2

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I would like to place Icons or Images or User Controls inside the activity by dragging and placing at some position on the activity in Android 2.2. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please share some link which helped you tracing this problem, because I have a similar problem to trace out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:
http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/simple-drag-n-drop-on-android.html

This is for buttons but I am pretty sure can be done easily with icons and images and buttons. :)

Comment: I already referred that link, anyways Thank you , the below link helped me for dragging and dropping images. 

http://androidtel.com/?p=6938